# ¿Por qué llamamos "tirillas" a alguien que es "poca cosa"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología

Me gusta mucho la palabra *tirillas*:

> [**tirillas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZrDvlFW)
>
> Tb. tirilla.
>
> Del dim. de tira.
>
> 1. m. y f. coloq. Persona delgada y endeble. U. t. c. adj.

Se usa en España (no sé si en otros sitios) para definir a alguien que es "poca cosa", es decir, flojo, etc.

La explicación "`del diminutivo de tira`" me parece algo parca, ¿alguien sabe darle una explicación más extendida?. Y también, ¿se usa en otros países de habla castellana?

Comment: No se usa en Colombia para personas flacas. Aquí tirilla es la cinta de papel que sale en el punto de pago del supermercado con los precios de los artículos comprados y el total a pagar. Cualquier cinta de papel similar a la anterior también la llamamos tirilla. Para cualquiera otro tipo de tira pequeña usamos el diminutivo Tirita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En España sí que se usa. En los ámbitos familiares y amigables es bastante usada, ya que tiene un carácter despectivo o jocoso y fuera de esos ámbitos puede acarrear problemas.

El origen de la palabra viene por antonomasia al paralelismo que viene de alguien que es muy endeble y delgado, y que por tanto suele hacerse daño y lleva tiritas o bien por la sinonímia de que una tira es algo alargado y endeble. Al ser una expresión coloquial el origen es desconocido, pero estas son las referencias más plausibles.

No sé si la palabra "tirita" es muy usada fuera de España, pero para la gente que no lo sepa, tirita se puede asociar a "band aid" en inglés.

Referencias: http://365palabras.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/tirillas.html

> Tirillas es un término coloquial que proviene de la voz tira (pieza
>   larga y delgada de tela, papel, cuero…) de ahí que este sustantivo se
>   emplee para denominar a un hombre delgado, endeble, flaco, enjuto e
>   incluso... escuchimizado. ;-)

Comment: Mmm entonces asumes que "tirillas" viene de alguien que usa "tiritas". Me parece curioso cuanto menos, pues la "tirita" es un invento relativamente nuevo que viene de "Tiritas®, marca reg". Esto es, no más de cien años a lo sumo.

Comment: Tirita cómo elemento curativo o farmacéutico reciente si, pero los vendajes o "tiras" vienen de muy atrás. Se puede asociar como decía a alguien que es endeble o poca cosa, que suele hacerse daño y por tanto llevar vendas, tiras o tiritas.

Answer (score 0):

No se usa en Perú, pero la correlacion del significado subsiste para determinar alguien que es poca cosa. Por ejemplo: "mequetrefe" = Hombre entremetido, bullicioso y de poco provecho (según RAE). También se aplica para señalar una persona endeble (sentido inverso "tirillas").